# Hide rows in a table depending the current month with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I created a HTML table which conatins "Month" column. What I would like to do is only show the rows that matches the current month (this I already accomplished), but also the previuos month.Thanks in advance. Just FYI, I'm new with jQuery.
This what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<table class="theTable">
<tr>
    <th class="theMonth">Month</th>
    <th>Value</th><th>Month Number</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="theMonth">October</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>  
<tr>
    <td class="theMonth">November</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>  
<tr>
    <td class="theMonth">December</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>  
<tr>
    <td class="theMonth">January</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td class="theMonth">February</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="theMonth">March</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="theMonth">April</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="theMonth">May</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="theMonth">June</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="theMonth">July</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="theMonth">August</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="theMonth">September</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>12</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

jQUery:

```
$(function(){monthColumn();});
function monthColumn()
{
    rows = [];
    $('.theMonth').each(function()
    {  
        var rowText = $(this).text();
        rows.push(rowText);

        var theDate=new Date();
        var month=new Array();
        month[0]="October";
        month[1]="November";
        month[2]="December";
        month[3]="January";
        month[4]="February";
        month[5]="March";
        month[6]="April";
        month[7]="May";
        month[8]="June";
        month[9]="July";
        month[10]="August";
        month[11]="September";
        var n = month[theDate.getMonth()-1]; 
        var m = month[theDate.getMonth()-2] //Testing
        if ( rowText == n)
        {
            $('.theMonth').not(this).parent().hide();
        }
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$('.theMonth').not(this).parent().hide();
```

to this:

```
$('.theMonth').parent().hide();
$(this).parent().show();
$(this).parent().prev().show();
```

This is a crazy derpy hack, since the way you are doing this in a loop is not optimized this is just to show you an example of what you could do.  This hides them all then shows the ones you want.  You could alternatively get all of them, iterate through them, and hide them each individually not hiding the ones you want.

Better:

```
if ( rowText !== n && rowText !== m)
  {
    $(this).parent().hide();
  }
```

This actually is better in that it hides the row as it is setting it up when it detects its not in the "to show" cool club.

PS, you prolly don't need to make that month array inside of the .each loop... you could just make it once outside of that loop.

Comment: Thanks so much Nick, it work perfectly. Thank you for the suggestion regarding the month array, I changed that too.

Comment: Nick. thanks again for your help, but i have another problem. We are in January (Month[0], that means that the variable n will have a negative value "month[theDate.getMonth()-1]". In this case the condition will not work. I would try Math.abs, but that would give me the worng month. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance. PS. I tried switch/case, but it became pretty long, and I' sure there is a better option out there.

Comment: You could just take that logic outside of the month[].  Something like:
var prevMonth = theDate.getMonth()-1;
prevMonth = prevMonth === -1 ? 12 : prevMonth;
month[prevMonth]...